# Не удаётся передать в иной поток данные.(общение двух потоков)

Tags: qt, многопоточность, qt5

В создаю второй поток, в котором происходит отправка сообщения.
Но сообщения бывают разные и по сему туда постоянно отправляются настройки для приёма сообщения.
И у меня не выходит передать в другой поток эти настройки (три переменных).

Вот как я реализую эту задумку в коде:

```
  //--- создание отдельного потока для приёма сообщений
    // поток приёма данных
    QThread *thread = new QThread(); // инициализ класс потока
    MyThread_priem *mythread_priem = new MyThread_priem(); // инициализируем второй класс
    connect(this,SIGNAL(sig_init_CAN_param()),mythread_priem,SLOT(Start_tehn_per(unsigned char,unsigned short,unsigned char)));
    connect(thread,SIGNAL(started()),mythread_priem,SLOT(Receiving_a_Message())); // наследуем thread  а не от MyMainWindows-a
    connect(mythread_priem,SIGNAL(update_m(ulong,unsigned char,unsigned char,QString,ulong,unsigned short,unsigned short)),this,
            SLOT(RepaintReceivedMessage(ulong,unsigned char,unsigned char,QString,ulong,unsigned short,unsigned short))); // соединение источника данных с приемником

    mythread_priem->moveToThread(thread); // отправляем в поток
    thread->start(); // цикл обработки сообщения в потоке
```

Место объявления :

```
 class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    //--    переменные
    unsigned char  can_usb;
    unsigned short speed_bit;             // скорость в битах
    unsigned char  can_device;
    int tex_d_divice;                     // датчик для взаимодействия и управления изм характеристик

signals:
    void sig_init_CAN_param(unsigned char, unsigned short, unsigned char);              // сигнал который явл. датчиком аппаратного изменения КАНа

............................
};


// класс для приёма в отдельном потоке данных
class MyThread_priem: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
     public:
          void Clear_Struct();
          //    void Receiving_a_Message();
          //--    переменные
          unsigned char  can_usb;
          unsigned short speed_bit;             // скорость в битах
          unsigned char  can_device;
...........................

public slots:
    void Receiving_a_Message(); // способ через нажатие кнопки
    static void ProcessMessage(TPCANMsg_priem msg); // отчёт о принятии сообщения
    void Start_tehn_per(unsigned char, unsigned short, unsigned char); //передача настроек сообщения
};
```

Место заполнения :

```
void MainWindow::USB_CAN_option()
{
   ..........................
    if(ui->aPCAN_USBBUS8->isChecked()){
        can_usb = 0x58;
    }
    qDebug() << "can_usb = " << can_usb;
    if (tex_d_divice <3)
        tex_d_divice++;
    if(tex_d_divice >=3)
        sig_init_CAN_param(can_usb, speed_bit, can_device);
}
```

Ну и сам вызов :

```
void MyThread_priem::Start_tehn_per(unsigned char a, unsigned b, unsigned c)
{
     can_usb = a;
     speed_bit = b;              
     can_device = c;
}
```

В ответ мне приходит ошибка:

```
  ошибка: prototype for 'void MyThread_priem::Start_tehn_per(unsigned char, unsigned int, unsigned int)' does not match any in class 'MyThread_priem'
 void MyThread_priem::Start_tehn_per(unsigned char a, unsigned b, unsigned c)
      ^

 ошибка: candidate is: void MyThread_priem::Start_tehn_per(unsigned char, short unsigned int, unsigned char)
     void Start_tehn_per(unsigned char, unsigned short, unsigned char); //РїРµСЂРµРґР°С‡Р° РЅР°СЃС‚СЂРѕРµРє СЃРѕРѕР±С‰РµРЅРёСЏ
          ^
```

Что я делаю не так ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внимательно прочтите содержание сообщения об ошибке:

```
ошибка: prototype for 'void MyThread_priem::Start_tehn_per(unsigned char, unsigned int, unsigned int)' does not match any in class 'MyThread_priem'
```

У вас объявление и определение функции не совпадают:

В объявлении аргументы - `(unsigned char, unsigned short, unsigned char)`

В определении аргументы - `(unsigned char a, unsigned b, unsigned c)`

Соответственно, нужно исправить в определении:
`(unsigned char a, unsigned short b, unsigned char c)`